# Solving a complicated equation of order 5. completely parametrically

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, polynomials, parametric-functions

I have this equation and it takes so much time to solve. i would appreciate some guidance how to solve it. 0<l<1 and 0<gamma<1 and -Pi/2<theta<Pi/2 and w is real and positive. other variable are just constant numbers and all positive.

```
Subscript[\[Lambda], 1] = 
Subscript[s, 1]*Sqrt[q^2 + w^2 + 1] /. 
q -> (w*Sin[\[Theta]] + I*\[Gamma])/Cos[\[Theta]] // FullSimplify;

Subscript[\[Lambda], 2] = 
Subscript[s, 2]*Sqrt[q^2 + w^2 + l^2] /. 
q -> (w*Sin[\[Theta]] + I*\[Gamma])/Cos[\[Theta]] // FullSimplify;

Solve[Subscript[\[Lambda], 
 1]*(l^2 + (-Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + Subscript[\[Alpha], 3])*
   Subscript[\[Lambda], 2]^2 + (1 + 
     Subscript[\[Alpha], 
      1])*(w^2 + (I*\[Gamma]*Sec[\[Theta]] + 
        w*Tan[\[Theta]])^2))*
     ((-Subscript[C, 1133])*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 
    3]*(w^2 + (I*\[Gamma]*Sec[\[Theta]] + w*Tan[\[Theta]])^2) + 
  Subscript[C, 
    3333]*(l^2 - 
     Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]*Subscript[\[Lambda], 1]^2 + 
             (1 + 
        Subscript[\[Alpha], 
         1])*(w^2 + (I*\[Gamma]*Sec[\[Theta]] + 
           w*Tan[\[Theta]])^2))) - 
Subscript[\[Lambda], 
 2]*(l^2 + (-Subscript[\[Alpha], 2] + Subscript[\[Alpha], 3])*
   Subscript[\[Lambda], 1]^2 + 
        (1 + 
     Subscript[\[Alpha], 
      1])*(w^2 + (I*\[Gamma]*Sec[\[Theta]] + 
        w*Tan[\[Theta]])^2))*((-Subscript[C, 1133])*
   Subscript[\[Alpha], 
    3]*(w^2 + (I*\[Gamma]*Sec[\[Theta]] + w*Tan[\[Theta]])^2) + 
        
  Subscript[C, 
    3333]*(l^2 - 
     Subscript[\[Alpha], 2]*
      Subscript[\[Lambda], 2]^2 + (1 + 
        Subscript[\[Alpha], 
         1])*(w^2 + (I*\[Gamma]*Sec[\[Theta]] + 
           w*Tan[\[Theta]])^2))) == 0, w]
```

Comment: You have an equation of the order 4 with huge coefficients that have generic values. The solution of such an equation one, in principle, can get with Mathematica using a few simple tricks. However, it will be (1) huge and, therefore, (2) useless. That is, one will be unable to analyze it or use it further.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch It turns out that there are either four or six solutions depending on the values of the parameters.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Did you understand my answer such that I think that there is only one solution to the equation of the fourth order? No. The word "one" stays in my answer as a part of the expression "one can get..."

Answer (score 4):

Considerable progress can be made as follows.  First, replace `Subscript` in the equation, because it slows calculations and is inconvenient besides.  This can be done by defining

```
f[z1_, z2_] := ToExpression[StringJoin @@ (ToString /@ {z1, z2})]
```

and then use `/.Subscript -> f` on the equation appearing in `Solve` in the question.  The result is

```
eq = 
s1 Sqrt[1 + w^2 + (I γ Sec[θ] + w Tan[θ])^2] (l^2 + (1 + α1) (w^2 + (I γ 
    Sec[θ] + w Tan[θ])^2) + s2^2 (-α2 + α3) (l^2 + w^2 + (I γ Sec[θ] + 
    w Tan[θ])^2)) (-C1133 α3 (w^2 + (I γ Sec[θ] + w Tan[θ])^2) + 
    C3333 (l^2 + (1 + α1) (w^2 + (I γ Sec[θ] + w Tan[θ])^2) - 
    s1^2 α2 (1 + w^2 + (I γ Sec[θ] + w Tan[θ])^2))) - 
s2 Sqrt[l^2 + w^2 + (I γ Sec[θ] +  w Tan[θ])^2] (l^2 + (1 + α1) (w^2 + (I γ 
    Sec[θ] + w Tan[θ])^2) + s1^2 (-α2 + α3) (1 + w^2 + (I γ Sec[θ] + 
    w Tan[θ])^2)) (-C1133 α3 (w^2 + (I γ Sec[θ] + w Tan[θ])^2) + 
    C3333 (l^2 + (1 + α1) (w^2 + (I γ Sec[θ] + w Tan[θ])^2) - 
    s2^2 α2 (l^2 + w^2 + (I γ Sec[θ] + w Tan[θ])^2))) == 0
```

Notice that `w` appears only in the combination, `w^2 + (I γ Sec[θ] + w Tan[θ])^2`, so significant simplification can be achieved by the substitution,

```
eq1 = eq /. w^2 -> x - (I γ Sec[θ] + w Tan[θ])^2
(* -s2 Sqrt[l^2 + x] (C3333 (l^2 + x (1 + α1) - s2^2 (l^2 + x) α2) - 
   C1133 x α3) (l^2 + x (1 + α1) + s1^2 (1 + x) (-α2 + α3)) + 
   s1 Sqrt[1 + x] (C3333 (l^2 + x (1 + α1) - s1^2 (1 + x) α2) - 
   C1133 x α3) (l^2 + x (1 + α1) + s2^2 (l^2 + x) (-α2 + α3)) == 0 *)
```

with `w` obtained from `x` by

```
Simplify[Solve[w^2 + (I γ Sec[θ] + w Tan[θ])^2 == x, w], -Pi/2 < θ < Pi/2]
(* {{w -> -Cos[θ] (Sqrt[x + γ^2] + I γ Tan[θ])}, 
    {w -> Sqrt[x + γ^2] Cos[θ] - I γ Sin[θ]}} *)
```

An obvious choice to obtain real `w > 0` is `θ = 0`, which yields, `w -> Sqrt[x + γ^2]`, positive real for `x > -γ^2`.  An approach for obtaining `x` begins by eliminating the `Sqrt`s from `eq1` and factoring the result.

```
eq1sq = Subtract @@ (eq1[[1, 1]]^2 == eq1[[1, 2]]^2);
fac1 = FactorList[eq1sq];
LeafCount /@ First[Transpose[%]]
(* {1, 24, 4908} *)
```

The second factor is of manageable size and can be solved readily.

```
x12 = Solve[fac1[[2, 1]] == 0, x] // Simplify // Flatten
(* {x -> (-s1^2 + l^2 s2^2)/(s1^2 - s2^2)} *)
```

That it actually satisfies the original equation is verified by

```
Simplify[eq1 /. x12, s1 > 0 && s2 > 0]
(* True *)
```

Here is a sample plot of `w` vs `{s1, s2}`

```
Quiet@Plot3D[Sqrt[(-s1^2 + l^2 s2^2)/(s1^2 - s2^2) + γ^2] 
    /. {l -> 1/2, γ -> 1/2}, {s2, 0, 5}, {s1, 0, 5}, 
    AxesLabel -> {s2, s1, w}, PlotLabel -> "{l -> 1/2, γ -> 1/2}", 
    LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

The larger factor also can be solved by

```
Collect[fac1[[3, 1]], x, Simplify];
Solve[% == 0, x]
```

but the four resulting solutions are unmanageably complicated.  Moreover, two or three of them (depending on the choice of parameter values) do not satisfy the original equation.  Of course, `eq1` can be solved numerical for any specific parameters; i.e.,

```
param1 = C1133 -> 0.820599, C3333 -> 0.84379, l -> 0.157808, s1 -> 0.94172, 
    s2 -> 0.768998, α1 -> 0.651002, α2 -> 0.8877, α3 -> 0.474658}
Flatten@Solve[Simplify[0 == eq1 /. SetPrecision[param1, 30]]]
(* {x -> -2.951519117927659465922, x -> -2.096574605386734359552, 
    x -> -0.01329052999440164484502} *)
```

The third root leads to a positive real value for `w` for most values of `γ`.